# haskell yesod file upload input file not found

Tags: haskell, yesod

handlers:

```
getFuploadR=defaultLayout $ do
    [whamlet|
     <form method=post>
        <input type=file name=file>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit
    |]
postFuploadR=do
  imgnfo<-runInputPost $ ireq fileField "file"
  bytes <- runResourceT $ fileSource imgnfo $$ sinkLbs
  liftIO $ write2server bytes "1.jpg"
```

it compiles ok.after select sth to upload and submit,i just get:

Invalid Arguments

Input not found: file

Comment: You need to set the enctype on the form itself to multipart/form-data

Comment: bingo!i just find out that myself! please answer that formally so i can make it the right one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the enctype on the form itself to multipart/form-data